# Special Character to Replace Spaces in a Text Field in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have searched a lot but I have failed to find a solution to my problem.

I have a text field in which the user enters data. The entered text may contain spaces, and I want to replace those occurrences with the sequence `%20`.

It does not matter how many spaces there are; whenever a space comes it should be replaced with `%20`.

Comment: it is easy `urlString = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet]];`

Comment: can u explain in answer? @MikeAlter

Comment: It is not answer.  but stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters will automatically add %20 where the space in string Try IT

Comment: Please check my answer. :) @Oneeb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace space with %20

```
  @implementation ViewController
{
 NSString *result
}

result=self.txtField.text;
result=[result stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
```

and if your want to edit when user is entering text in TextField then use this in TextFiled's TextChanged Event.

Write this line in ViewDidLoad

```
[self.txtField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

and

```
-(void)textFieldDidChange :(UITextField *)theTextField{
result=self.txtField.text;
result=[result stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
//just use this result where you want 
}
```

Comment: Bro ur code is working fine but this character %20 is dispalyed on the screen when we give space , i want it not to show on screen , when user give space it should display a space in a textfield but in backend when the value is pass it should pass %20 where there is a space. @Zaheer Udeen Babar

Comment: @Oneeb just set the result to your variable where you want to use it? just   dont assign result back to text field, remove self.txtField.text=result;

Comment: remove this line self.txtField.text=result; as @user1000 suggested.

Comment: i have remove this line self.txtField.text=result;  but it is not working now. @user1000

Comment: @Oneeb where do you want to use this result with %20 instead of spaces?

Comment: Actually when user enter any text in a textfield when it enter space on screen only space should be seen but when it pass the value to another place , this character %20 should go where user enter space. @user1000

Comment: @Oneeb declare result at class level. I have edited the code now you can use it.

Comment: Now its working perfect thanks a lot.:) @ZaheerUdeenBabar

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code:

**Objective C:**

```
 NSString *string =   textField.text;

           string = [string stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet]];
```

**Swift:**

```
var string: String = textField.text
string = string.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.alphanumerics)
```

Returns a new string made from the receiver by replacing all characters not in the allowedCharacters set with percent encoded characters.

Comment: Thanks i got my answer. @Surabh Jain

Comment: no i haven't i got answer before this.:) @Saurabh Jain